# How to update unshare package (unrecognized option '--fork')?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, manpage

I'm facing to an issue. I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.
The execution of a program fails with the error:

```
unshare: unrecognized option '--fork'
```

I found on the web two man pages for 'unshare' package:

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/unshare (I have this one, in fact without --fork option)
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html (with the --fork option)

This pakage is included in 'util-linux' package. I would like to know how to switch to the other 'unshare' in order to have the --fork option available.

I already tried to upgrade my Ubuntu, but unshare is not upgraded.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/unshare.1.html) lists `--fork`. How did you install it?

Comment: I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, unshare si provided inside, I don't install anything else...

Comment: Hmm. Looks like the option was only added in 14.10. You may have to use a PPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xeron-oskom/+archive/ubuntu/util-linux) by Ivan Larionov who built a newer package from Debian experimental to try and fix [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1012081). I haven't tested it, so *caveat emptor*. See [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) if you don't know what a PPA is.

Comment: the ppa solved it for me as well, running a pretty fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS